# Detecting a date value from a cell

Tags: excel, office-js

I am using the Office JS API to interact with a spreadsheet. I am reading a series of values from a sheet without knowing the expected data types in advance.

How can I determine whether a value is a date? Date values are returned as numeric values, so it's difficult to make the determination. The best way I've found so far is to interrogate the `numberFormat` property and check if the format is "date-like", however it's a bit flimsy.

Is there any built in way using the API to have it report to me that it's a date?

Comment: Excel does not have a native Date or Time data type - so there is no reliable way of determining if a cell is supposed to be a date. Using NumberFormat is probably the best you can do.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams Please make your comment an answer.

Comment: There does seem to be some precedent for it. When writing a `VSTO` addin, getting the value of a cell will return a `DateTime` instance where the value is a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not have a native Date or Time or Currency data type - so there is no reliable way of determining if a cell is supposed to be a date. Using NumberFormat is probably the best you can do from JavaScript

In the VBA and COM-Interop APIs Range.Value returns a date or currency data type for cells formatted as dates or currency, and Range.Value2 always returns a double regardless of formatting.